# Is there a cleaner/simpler way to achieve 2 aligned columns, text/image?

Tags: html, css, layout

I am very new to programming and I would like to know if there is a simpler way of achieving this: box of text on the left and image on the right both aligned. I added a padding-top to account for a navigation menu. Could I have done this with fewer code lines??

```
<div class="intro">
    <div id="text">
        <h2 id="head">Quiénes Somos</h2>
        <p id="info"> text text text text</p>
    </div>

    <div id="image">
        <img id="obj" src="images/pyme.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
    .intro {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 135px;
}

.intro #text {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 40%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.intro #text #head {
    background-color: #d45029;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

.intro #text #info {
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-indent: 50px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.intro #image {
    width: 40%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.intro #image #obj {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

And here's a fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/dqx1qznb/). I've read that it would be much easier using floats but I tried and failed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use `display: flex` on the parent and it will put the columns a horizontal row, then no need for `inline-block`  https://jsfiddle.net/dqx1qznb/1/

Comment: whoa, super simple stuff! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use percents, display:block, and floats for this stuff. Then I fine-tune margin and padding based on what I want to do.

**html**

```
<div class="divs-wrapper">
    <div class="div-1">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ac dictum lectus, id tristique elit. Integer tincidunt sollicitudin magna a congue.</p>
    </div>  
    <div class="div-2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ac dictum lectus, id tristique elit. Integer tincidunt sollicitudin magna a congue.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.divs-wrapper {
    width: 80%;/* width of wrapper */
    display: block;/* display block allows margin and width setting */
    margin: 0 auto;/* centers wrapper in 100% width body */
}

.div-1 {
    width: 49%;/* div 1 half width of wrapper */
    display: block;/* display block allows floats */
    float: left;/* float left to allow alignment of elements next to eachother */
    padding: .5%;/* padding for spacing */
}

.div-2 {
    width: 49%;/* div 2 half width of wrapper */
    display: block;/* display block allows floats */
    float: left;/* float left to allow alignment of elements next to eachother */
    padding: .5%;/* padding for spacing */
}
```

**My Demo**
https://codepen.io/rw1982/pen/eWwZjB

If you are new to html and css, and you want to set up columns or grids to work on a responsive level. Try these links to get started.

**Responsive Grid**
http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/

Comment: If you want to step it up, check out how flex box works.
**Flex-Box Demo**
http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely check the sites out. This answer makes me understand better how divs behave. I am trying to create the layout by adding borders to see how my content would look. Why is that when I add borders to your css it puts one element on top of the other?

Comment: I would research how the box model works. Since I am using percents in the example, adding borders to it might make it go over 100% width of the element. Percents are touchy. Feel free to either play with the width of the parent elements or just use pixels, ems, or (better yet) rems to simplify things temporarily. There are many ways to do this, you could even add all of your content in one div and use this method to add columns. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

Answer (score 0):

divs are `display: block` by default, which means they will stretch the full width of their container unless their width is specified (or you change `display` to something else).

If you want to use float style, you need to take all the content out of individual divs, which  would leave you something like this:

```
<div class="intro">
  <img style = "float: right; max-width: 50%" id="obj" src="http://i.imgur.com/8EL2PCM.jpg">
  <h2 id="head">text text</h2>
  <p id="info"> text text text text text text</p>
</div>
```

Because `p` and `img` are inline by default, they don't take up any more space than they need. Note that I've set styles to the image inline. You could move these to your stylesheet to get the same effect. Images by default will render at their actual size, which is why I set the `max-width` to 50%. You would not need to do this if the image you're using is already at the size at which you'd like it to render.

If you want to apply styles across all your text, rather than a `div`, wrap your text in a `span`  which is the default `display: inline` element. Or just give your `p` tags classes or ids. These are `display:inline` as well.

Comment: This basically did what I wanted without all the extra code. I am looking to have the text and the image on the center of the display though. Should I apply percentage margins?

Comment: "display: inline" elements can be centered with the "text-align" property so all you'd have to do is add "text-align:center" to the #intro div. This will center-justify the text too though. If you want to move the content away from the edges, yeah, you can use margins. One thing you might look into which is pretty easy to use for layouts is Bootstrap... Maybe not now but once you have a decent understanding of HTML and CSS, it gives you easy tools for controlling stuff like margins and adjusting the layout to suit different screen sizes.

Comment: one other thing you might consider if you don't want the text to butt up against the image is adding padding to the image. padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:10px; or whatever will give the image some room.